# Writing a new column if contents of one list is in another in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

Suppose I have several lists of colors, where each list correspond to a given person. I want to create a master list, so I know which person has has what colors in their list.

Here's example data:

```
Sarah <- c("Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Pink")
Ben <- c("Black", "White", "Silver", "Pink", "Red", "Purple")
Jenny <- c("Green", "Orange", "Gold")

people <- list(Sarah, Ben, Jenny)
names(people) <- c("Sarah", "Ben", "Jenny")
allcolors <- c( Sarah, Ben, Jenny)

colorSet <- data.frame(colors = allcolors)
```

I want a master sheet, where reach row corresponds to a color and each column corresponds to a person.  If the person has a color in their list, then that cell would be TRUE, if they do not have a color in their list then it would be FALSE.

This is what I tried to far, but it hasn't worked.

```
for (i in 1:length(people)) {

   sub_people <- people[[i]]
   sub_people_name <- names(people[i])
   colorSet$x <- ifelse(which(sub_people %in% colorSet$colors), TRUE, FALSE)
   names(colorSet)[names(colorSet) == x] <- sub_people_name

 }
```

This is the error I get:

Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "x", value = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE,  : 
  replacement has 5 rows, data has 14

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: One convoluted way: `\`class<-\`(table(stack(mget(c("Sarah", "Ben", "Jenny")))), "logical")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work with base R:

```
colorSet$Sarah <- colorSet$colors %in% Sarah
colorSet$Ben <- colorSet$colors %in% Ben
colorSet$Jenny <- colorSet$colors %in% Jenny
```

Where `colorSet` returns:

> ```
>    colors Sarah   Ben Jenny
> 1     Red  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
> 2    Blue  TRUE FALSE FALSE
> 3  Yellow  TRUE FALSE FALSE
> 4   Green  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
> 5    Pink  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
> 6   Black FALSE  TRUE FALSE
> 7   White FALSE  TRUE FALSE
> 8  Silver FALSE  TRUE FALSE
> 9    Pink  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
> 10    Red  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
> 11 Purple FALSE  TRUE FALSE
> 12  Green  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
> 13 Orange FALSE FALSE  TRUE
> 14   Gold FALSE FALSE  TRUE
> ```

This should also work:

```
l <- rbind.data.frame(lapply(people, function(x) colorSet$colors %in% x))
l$colors <- colorSet$colors
```

With `purrr` we could do:

```
purrr::map_df(people, function(x) colorSet$colors %in% x)

# Alternatively, if you prefer formula syntax
purrr::map_df(people, ~ colorSet$colors %in% .)
```

Returns:

> ```
> # A tibble: 14 x 3
>    Sarah Ben   Jenny
>    <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
>  1 TRUE  TRUE  FALSE
>  2 TRUE  FALSE FALSE
>  3 TRUE  FALSE FALSE
>  4 TRUE  FALSE TRUE 
>  5 TRUE  TRUE  FALSE
>  6 FALSE TRUE  FALSE
>  7 FALSE TRUE  FALSE
>  8 FALSE TRUE  FALSE
>  9 TRUE  TRUE  FALSE
> 10 TRUE  TRUE  FALSE
> 11 FALSE TRUE  FALSE
> 12 TRUE  FALSE TRUE 
> 13 FALSE FALSE TRUE 
> 14 FALSE FALSE TRUE
> ```

Comment: I substituted my ifelse() statement with your suggestion and it worked!  I'll mark your answer as correct!

Comment: Happy to help !

Answer (score 0):

```
Sarah <- c("Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Pink")
Ben <- c("Black", "White", "Silver", "Pink", "Red", "Purple")
Jenny <- c("Green", "Orange", "Gold")

m_color <-unique(c(Sarah,Ben,Jenny))

TF <-data.frame(color = m_color)

TF$Sarah <- m_color%in%Sarah
TF$Ben <- m_color%in%Ben
TF$Jenny <- m_color%in%Jenny
```

Answer (score 0):

Following uses `sapply`. This way one doesn't have to names of people repeatedly.

```
all_colours <- unique(allcolors)
tab <- sapply(people, function(x) all_colours %in% x)
rownames(tab) <- all_colours

tab
#        Sarah   Ben Jenny
# Red     TRUE  TRUE FALSE
# Blue    TRUE FALSE FALSE
# Yellow  TRUE FALSE FALSE
# Green   TRUE FALSE  TRUE
# Pink    TRUE  TRUE FALSE
# Black  FALSE  TRUE FALSE
# White  FALSE  TRUE FALSE
# Silver FALSE  TRUE FALSE
# Purple FALSE  TRUE FALSE
# Orange FALSE FALSE  TRUE
# Gold   FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```